# Generate warning in R for more than one items

Tags: r, warnings

I have a question about generating warnings for more than one items at a time in R. Please refer to the following dataframe and codes:

Dataframe dat:

```
  inputs var1 var2
A    1    a    1
B    2    b    3
B    3    b   NA
C    4    d   NA
C    5    e    4

if (any(duplicated(dat$inputs))==T){
  warning(paste("The following inputs: ", dat$inputs[duplicated(dat$inputs)],"is duplicated.",sep=""))
}
```

As you can see both B and C will be shown in the warning, like:

```
Warning message:
The following inputs: B is duplicated.The following inputs: C is duplicated.
```

I'm okay with such warning message output, but it is not ideal. Is there a way to combine the two sentences and make it look like:

```
Warning message:
The following inputs: B,C are duplicated.
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your attention and time.

Helene

Comment: Have a look at `sprintf` and the `"%s"` part

Comment: Note that `paste` will recycle to fit the longest input. Try out `paste("test", 1:5, "test again")` and see what happens. As Vlo pointed out below, the `collapse` option is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your code to run, so I made up some/modified your code/data.

```
dat = read.table(text = "
inputs var1 var2 var3
A    1    a    1
B    2    b    3
B    3    b   NA
C    4    d   NA
C    5    e    4", header = T)


if (any(b<-duplicated(dat$inputs))){
  if (length(c<-unique(dat$inputs[b]))>1) {warning(paste0("The following inputs: ", paste0(c, collapse=", "), " are duplicated."))} else
  {warning(paste0("The following input: ", paste0(c, collapse=", "), " is duplicated."))}
}


Warning message:
The following inputs: B, C are duplicated.
```

Single duplicate

```
dat = read.table(text = "
inputs var1 var2 var3
A    1    a    1
A    2    b    3
E    3    b   NA
C    4    d   NA
G    5    e    4", header = T)

Warning message:
The following input: A is duplicated.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot -  it works. Didn't know I can use a paste() inside of another. I'm still new to R.

Comment: `any(duplicated(...))` is the same as `anyDuplicated()`